# How should I realise gradient descent method with these conditions?

Tags: math, gradient-descent, minimization

I have a task to write optisation of a functional using gradient descent metode. I've got a functional with parameters a and b. For example, a*x + b. I need to find a and b parameters to minimize the functional.
I've also got (x,y) pairs. But I don't know how to apply this method to a and b.

I found out how to find function extremum with gradient descent method but there's very few information about functionals. I was told that I should use L1 or L2 norm to solve my problem. But I can't understand how to apply this to GD realisation to minimize a and b.
If it is imortant, I write in C#.

Comment: Hi. You are using very imprecise vocabulary and I think it makes everything more confused, both in this post and in your head, that it could otherwise be. I don't think `a*x + b` is a "functional"; I also don't think you want to "minimize" `a * x + b`. I think what you want, is to find `a` and `b` that makes all of the approximations `y ≈ a * x + b` as close as possible for your given `(x, y)` pairs. One way to do this is to decide on an "error function" that maps (a, b) to "how bad the approximations are on all the (x, y) pairs", and to find the pair (a, b) that minimises this error function.